# Kivy SDL2 Python3.5 build crashing on android 5 and above

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I have been trying for a while to build an application using Kivy SDL2 with python3crystax and everything works as expected.
I made the minimum api to be 16 and the target to be 21 (as this is the most crystax has at the moment) 
The application works fine on any android below 5 but crashes on 5 or above. In logcat all i manage to see with the filter `"-s AdBuddiz:D python:D"` is that it stops working when it gets here:

```
I/python  (10645): Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
I/python  (10645): AND: Ran string
I/python  (10645): Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
I/python  (10645): main.py
I/python  (10645): [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 19)
I/python  (10645): [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
I/python  (10645): [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/data/f4f.ddddd.com.f4f/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-06-12_0.txt
I/python  (10645): [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
I/python  (10645): [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.0 (default, Dec 24 2015, 05:56:40) 
I/python  (10645): [GCC 5.3 20151204]
I/python  (10645): [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
I/python  (10645): [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
I/python  (10645): [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
```

This is all I see before it crashes without any error, and it only crashes on android 5+ and only when using the SDL2 version of kivy.

My question is, why exactly does it crash?

EDIT:
After debugging further, i found the following error being displayed in logcat

```
E/WindowState( 1331): getStack: Window{33a025fb u0 f4d.ddddd.com.f4f/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} couldn't find taskId=249 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:776 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getWindowList:1347 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getNeedsMenuLw:715 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.updateSystemUiVisibilityLw:6862
```

EDIT 2:
After more debugging and trying other example applications, it appears to be something within my code that is making it crash on higher version android OSs. Will start stripping down the code and see where it crashes

EDIT 3:
Apparently what was crashing my application was my AdBuddiz implementation

```
from kivy.app import platform
if platform == 'android':
    from utils import PythonActivity, AdBuddiz


class AdsNetwork:
    def __init__(self):
        if platform == "android":
            AdBuddiz.setPublisherKey("TEST_PUBLISHER_KEY")  # replace the key with your app Key
            AdBuddiz.setTestModeActive()  # test mode will be active
            AdBuddiz.cacheAds(PythonActivity.mActivity)  # now we are caching the ads

    def show_ads(self):
        if platform == 'android':
AdBuddiz.showAd(PythonActivity.mActivity) #show a popup ad
```

Comment: Does [this linked app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.inclem.pyonicinterpreter3) work?

Comment: Yes it does work, do you think it's caused by my actual code? although i debugged it and seems to not be that as i have no issus with it on android bellow 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following:

For android bellow 5 the activity is called `org.renpy.android.PythonActivity`
so when we initialize AdBuddiz like the documentation tells us to, it will work for android versions bellow 5 but for android 5 and above, the activity class name is `org.kivy.android.PythonActivity` which will obviously fail if we try to autoclass using the old activity class name